# Is it safe to modify an Arc<Mutex<T>> from both a Rust thread and a foreign thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Are there any general rules, design documentation or something similar that explains how the Rust standard library deals with threads that were not spawned by `std::thread`?

I have a `cdylib` crate and want to use it from another language in a threaded manner:

```
use std::mem;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

type jlong = usize;
type SharedData = Arc<Mutex<u32>>;

struct Foo {
    data: SharedData,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn Java_com_example_Foo_init(shared_data: &SharedData) -> jlong {
    let this = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Foo { data: shared_data.clone() }));
    this as jlong
}

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
unsafe fn jlong_to_pointer<T>(val: jlong) -> *mut T {
    mem::transmute::<u32, *mut T>(val as u32)
}

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
unsafe fn jlong_to_pointer<T>(val: jlong) -> *mut T {
    mem::transmute::<jlong, *mut T>(val)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn Java_com_example_Foo_f(this: jlong) {
    let mut this = unsafe { jlong_to_pointer::<Foo>(this).as_mut().unwrap() };
    let data = this.data.clone();
    let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
    *data = *data + 5;
}
```

specifically in

```
let shared_data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(5));
let foo = Java_com_example_Foo_init(&shared_data);
```

is it safe to modify `shared_data` from a thread spawned by `thread::spawn` if `Java_com_example_Foo_f` will be called from an unknown JVM thread?

*[Possible reason why it can be bad.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17485)*

Comment: That issue is two years old and the information there is completely outdated.

Comment: @Shepmaster `There is no "Rust runtime"` and no thread-local-variables, that std objects like `mutexes` are expected to be initialized?

Comment: @Shepmaster look at bug report that I pointed, the problem was that when `rust thread` spawns it init some thread-local-variable, while thread spawns for example with raw `pthread_create`  it doesn't init `some thread-local-variable`, so when you use std from raw pthread, you use not initialized thread-local-variable

Comment: Do you disagree with [delnan's statement regarding that issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726128/rust-and-foreign-threads#comment68679951_40726128), which suggests that data is out of date? If so, perhaps you can provide further details as to why you disagree. For your queue example, *where is the item and where is the queue*? The functions take no arguments, so there cannot be any value added and it cannot be added to anything.

Comment: This question could seriously use an MCVE.

Comment: @Shepmaster I not agree and disagree (because of information how at now works runtime is part of answer to my question and I don't know answer), I just explains to you why `rust thread` can be different from `os thread` and why the way how work `rust runstime` is important.

Comment: @Shepmaster I mean runtime, like `C runtime` not like `java runtime`, and see https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html : ` There is a small amount of initialization code that runs before the user’s main function`

Comment: @Shepmaster: I have removed the secondary question about `Box::into_raw`/`Box::from_raw` which should get this question back into the fold. I would consider asking for design documentation akin to asking for citations of the standard/specifications in other languages: a way to ask for more than gut feeling or anecdotes.

Comment: @delnan: My main worry today would be how thread local storage is handled by those foreign threads. There seems to be a number of limitations particularly around the invocation of destructors.

Comment: @MatthieuM. how so? When would destructors even run for thread-local storage?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Apparently, for TLS, destructors run at the termination of the thread (note: apparently there is limitation that this holds true except for the main thread). That's what I got from reading `local.rs` at least.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The issue you linked relates to `librustrt`, which was removed before Rust 1.0. [RFC 230](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0230-remove-runtime.md), which removed `librustrt`, specifically notes:

> When embedding Rust code into other contexts -- whether calling from C code or embedding in high-level languages -- there is a fair amount of setup needed to provide the "runtime" infrastructure that `libstd` relies on. If `libstd` was instead bound to the native threading and I/O system, the embedding setup would be much simpler.

Additionally, see [PR #19654](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19654) which implemented that RFC:

> When using Rust in an embedded context, it should now be possible to call a Rust function directly as a C function with absolutely no setup, though in that case panics will cause the process to abort. In this regard, the C/Rust interface will look much like the C/C++ interface.

For current documentation, the [Rustonomicon chapter on FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#calling-rust-code-from-c)'s examples of Rust code to be called from C make use of `libstd` (including `Mutex`, I believe, though that's an implementation detail of `println!`) without any caveats relating to runtime setup.